# .gitconfig [alias] doesn't recognize strings

Tags: git, alias, git-config

I am trying to make an alias for my GIT that looks something like that:

```
[alias]
    send = !git add . && git commit -m "AUTOCOMMIT: $(date)" && git push
```

This alias is for minor modifications that do not need any message. The problem is that whenever I run `git send` it returns the following:

```
$ git send
error: pathspec 'Fri' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'Aug' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '22' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '11:31:18' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'PDT' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '2014' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

If I run the command manually there is no error:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "AUTOCOMMIT: $(date)"
[master] AUTOCOMMIT: Fri Aug 22 11:37:17 PDT 2014
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
$ git push
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 368 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To <gitRepo>.git
   master -> master
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If I use single quotes the ```$(date)``` doesn't get expanded, and I end up with the commit that says:
```AUTOCOMMIT: $(date)``` as a commit comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per `git-config(1)`, under [**CONFIGURATION FILE: Syntax**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#_syntax):

> String values may be entirely or partially enclosed in double
>   quotes. You need to enclose    variable values in double quotes if you
>   want to preserve leading or trailing whitespace,    or if the variable
>   value contains comment characters (i.e. it contains `#` or `;`). Double
>   quote `"` and backslash `\` characters in variable values must be escaped:
>   use `\"` for `"` and    `\\` for `\`.

You don’t strictly have to add a second set of quotes, so:

```
[alias]
    send = !git add . && git commit -m \"AUTOCOMMIT: $(date)\" && git push
```

Also, if you save your aliases using `git config`, you can avoid having to do the escaping manually:

```
$ git config --global \
    alias.send '!git add . && git commit -m "AUTOCOMMIT: $(date)" && git push'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by modifying the alias:

```
[alias]
    send = !git add . && git commit -m "\"AUTOCOMMIT: $(date)\"" && git push
```

The question is still there though: Why do I need to escape the `""`? I was expecting the whole string just be executed by the shell.